# Can we change the style of selected points?

Tags: javascript, plotly

In this boxplot generated by plotly.js, after selecting points, the non-selected points get an opacity of 0.2.

Is it possible to change the styling of selected and non-selected points ?

```js
var trace1 = {
  y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  type: 'box',
  selectedpoints : [1,2,5],
  boxpoints: 'all'
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Plotly.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
/* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [reference](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#box-selected), you can see that there are properties for "selected" and "unselected" markers which allows you to change their styling:

```js
var trace1 = {
  y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  type: 'box',
  selectedpoints: [1, 2, 5],
  boxpoints: 'all',
  selected: {
    marker: {
      color: '#ff0000',
      opacity: 0.8
    }
  },
  unselected: {
    marker: {
      color: '#00ff00',
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  }
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>
    /* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
  </script>
</body>
```